# Fauna returning 'unauthorized' when using Auth0 as a third party access provider

Tags: vuejs3, auth0, faunadb

I am trying to integrate Fauna and Auth0 into my Vue 3 app.

To achieve that I am following [this Auth0 guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BPV5.png) and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3YIzB70WQQ).

In short, I have configured Auth0 as a Provider inside Fauna. And I am sending the Auth0 generated JWT token as the Fauna secret. Fauna should then decode the JWT and give access to the call.

To test it out my code fetches some dummy "products" data from Fauna and prints it to the console.

But when I make the call it returns as `unauthorized`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script inside my Vue component that is making the call:

```
import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";
import { query as q, Client } from "faunadb";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Api",
  setup() {
    let apiMessage = null;
    let executed = false;
    const auth = inject("Auth");

    const callApi = async () => {
      const accessToken = await auth.getTokenSilently();
      console.log(accessToken);
      try {
        const client = new Client({ secret: accessToken });
        const { Paginate, Documents, Collection } = q;

        const data = await client.query(
          Paginate(Documents(Collection("products")))
        );

        console.log(data);
        apiMessage = data;
        executed = true;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${e.response.status}: ${e.response.statusText}'`;
      }
    };

    return {
      callApi,
    };

  },
});
```

Here is a copy of the `unauthorized` response object that is returned:

```
{
  "name": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "unauthorized",
  "description": "Unauthorized",
  "requestResult": {
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "",
    "query": null,
    "requestRaw": "{\"paginate\":{\"documents\":{\"collection\":\"products\"}}}",
    "requestContent": {
      "raw": {
        "paginate": {
          "raw": {
            "documents": {
              "raw": {
                "collection": "products"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responseRaw": "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"unauthorized\",\"description\":\"Unauthorized\"}]}",
    "responseContent": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "code": "unauthorized",
          "description": "Unauthorized"
        }
      ]
    },
    "statusCode": 401,
    "responseHeaders": {
      "content-length": "65",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "x-txn-time": "1634006015704445"
    },
    "startTime": 1634006014934,
    "endTime": 1634006015885
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The client has to be [initiated with some other values](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/javascript#instantiating-a-client-and-issuing-queries), most importantly is the `domain` value.

```
var client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: 'YOUR_FAUNA_SECRET',
  domain: 'db.fauna.com',
  // NOTE: Use the correct domain for your database's Region Group.
  port: 443,
  scheme: 'https',
})
```